# Should a many-to-many relationship define anything other than the relationship

Tags: database-design

Taking the typical products / categories many-to-many relationship you'd typically have a relationship like follows:

```
table -- ProductsCategories
column - ProductId
column - CategoryId
```

Is it ill advised to add other properties to that relationship, things that only exist on that specific relationship. Such as (please forgive my terrible examples, I'm not good at examples):

```
table -- ProductsCategories
column - ProductId
column - CategoryId
column - DiscountForProductsInThisCategory
column - CategoryImageForProductsInThisCategory
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A many to many relationship is simply a table with 2 one to many relationships, think of it as 3 tables with 2 relationships rather than 2 tables with a relationship and data associated with it. There is no difference in the implementation.

Either way it's perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 6):

Unless the data is specifically for that particular relationship, then avoid this, as you will end up duplicating a lot of data. In your example, the images are linked to the category, and so should be stored there. However, a timestamp indicating when the relationship was made and edited, as well as user-ids that created and modified the relationship, should be in that table.

Comment: Agreed, I would use the CategoryID to join to a table containing the discount for products in the category as it pertains to the Category, and not the relationship between category and product.  Adding a timestamp is related to the relationship.

Answer (score 5):

Of course you can store this information there. Anywhere else and it wouldn't be normalized.

Comment: +1: And, there are "higher order" relationships, also.  3-way relationships, for example, where the intermediate table has more than 2 FK's and may also have attributes.

Comment: +1 also. If those properties rely on the unique intersection of the two (or more) foreign keys, it's the right place for them.

Comment: Those two fields could be stored in the Category table whilst still being normalised.  Their name is 'x...InThisCategory', therefore they relate to the Category.  They don't relate to the 'relationship' itself.

Comment: Em, the particular egs given are incorrect there.  A LACK of Normalisation, and massive duplication.

Answer (score 3):

For example, if you have a table of Athletes and a table of Races. The join table AthleteRace represents that athlete's participation in that race, so you could have their race time in there as well.

The two exapmles you have:

```
column - DiscountForProductsInThisCategory
column - CategoryImageForProductsInThisCategory
```

belong in the Category table, as they relate to a Category, not to the membership of a product within a category.

Comment: Thanks, that would have been a much better example. I am pretty horrible at coming up with appropriate examples.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not the question to be considered.

If a column, eg. `DiscountForProductsInThisCategory` is 1::1 with the PK of Category, then the only correct place for it is Category.  In ProductCategory, it will be a massive duplication of data.

If a column is 1::1 with the relation (ProductId+CategoryId), then the only correct place for it is ProductCategory.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

A relationship can have attributes, IMO.  Although some design masters don't think so.

Consider the "enrolled" relationship between Students and Courses.  If a student could be enrolled either for credit or as an auditor,  it would make sense for this attribute to be stored in a table whose key is (StudentID, CourseID).  This table is the relationship table that catalogues which students are enrolle d in which courses.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is totally fine to add other fields to this table.  One example from things I have done is that I usually add a timestamp field so that I know when the relationship was created between the two entites.